# Which airlines provide cheap last day tickets in Nordic countries?

Tags: air-travel, norway, estonia, nordic-countries

I spend every month about 500 euros to two business trips in a month, sometimes three for 750 euros, in flying from Tallinn to Oslo.

I often pay a ticket for return just in case.
However, many times, I have to change my return date.
I often just buy a new ticket two days before the traveling.

I am using at the moment Star Alliance for my traveling: SAS and Estonian Air.

I am at the moment still at the Basic level in Star Alliance.
I have not done any business agreement with the airplane companies.

**What is the best way to get cheap tickets two days before traveling?**

Comment: Have you tried Air Baltic?  Or just http://www.skyscanner.com?

Comment: I have tried both of these. I do not want to use Skyscanner because of the reasons here http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/16602/why-is-buying-an-airline-ticket-from-the-company-more-expensive-than-from-an-agg. AirBaltic does not offer sufficient times for my travelling.

Comment: What do you mean sufficient?  You meant convenient?   I have looked at the Skyscanner and the tickets 2 days from today hare $198 so it is possible that the days you need to travel are peak days like Sunday and Friday...

Comment: I mean with sufficient in this case bad availability of flights for my needed times like evenings on Thursday.

Comment: If you have particular times that you have to fly you might be out of luck in terms of price.  The departures from Tallinn are rather scarce I count about 40 in total for the day.  Now with your criteria of leaving Thursday evening and arriving presumably on the same day you have no ability to take advantage of non-direct flights, so generally you will pay whatever the airlines want you to pay for flights like that.  Have you considered a ferry to Helsinki and then a flight?

Comment: I am leaving from Tartu to my travelling. So 185 km to Tallinn and 240 km to Riga. At the moment, a limiting factor is busses going to Riga. So possible solution would be to use a car and go to Riga instead: https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=Tartu,+Tartu+linn,+Estland&daddr=tallinn+to:Riga,+R%C4%ABgas+pils%C4%93ta,+Lettland&hl=sv&ie=UTF8&sll=58.054632,25.565186&sspn=1.909625,4.421997&geocode=FY3RegMdl8qXASn3PV3V2DbrRjEQbfwYbbMABA%3BFaHvigMdp7V5ASm_FlbfmZSSRjFwYvwYbbMABA%3BFZH7ZAMd4tBvASntPQflsM_uRjEw_vJozc8ABA&oq=riga&mra=ls&t=m&z=7 I am not sure if there are any other airplane fields around.

Comment: I'd choose Riga.  You have a lot more options frying from there.

Comment: Riga has much more flights going to Oslo. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AvTQai5bck2FdE0xa2JSWjQybFkzeldGdXNZNTV6V1E&usp=sharing I noticed one mistake in flights data. This http://www.osl.no/en/osl/flighttimetables says that no flights to Riga on Sunday, which is false.

Comment: Estonia is being moved off the maps of Europe (flight-wise) more and more... it's outrageous.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're leaving from Tartu and Riga is a viable alternative to the Tallinn airport and a much better option as a flight gateway.

According to the [flight schedule](http://www.riga-airport.com/en/main/flights/flight_schedules?d=Oslo%2FGardermoen&c=&fn=&fd[day]=&fd[month]=&fd[year]=) [Air Baltic](http://www.airbaltic.com/public/index.html) has at least 6 scheduled daily flights to Oslo/Gardermoen including 1 at 22:00 and one at 23:05, which will suit your schedule nicely.

You're right about the buses from Tartu to Riga.  [LUX Express](http://www.luxexpress.eu/en/timetable) doesn't seem to have a very convenient schedule, neither does [Ecoline](http://legacy.ecolines.net/index.php?s=84).

As far as airports are concerned the only other airport within a reasonable vicinity would be Pskov but nothing worth mentioning is flying to or from there.  The next major airport would be [Pulkovo](http://www.pulkovoairport.ru/en/) but personally I wouldn't bother with it.

**ADDITIONAL INFO** After checking flight schedule from [Pulkovo](http://www.pulkovoairport.ru/en/) to Oslo I really wouldn't bother...

Comment: Next task is to find parking hotels from Riga near the airport. I cannot find any big car rental companies in Tartu. The easiest way seems to be have a own car and organize the parking yourself.

Comment: @Masi Have you just checked their parking lots: http://www.riga-airport.com/en/main/passengers/services/parking-lots  Besides you earn points from Air Baltic every time you do. :)